# What is the uncontracted form of "won't ever"?

Tags: contractions

I read in a book lately:

> This is my home and it **won't ever** be the same again.

I was wondering whether the proper uncontracted form would be:

> This is my home and it **will not ever** be the same again.

Or:

> This is my home and it **will never** be the same again.

Are all of the 3 above grammatical? Are there any differences between any of them?

I'm asking because the second sentence seems to be quite unnatural, although I can't find any reason why it should be grammatically incorrect. The same would apply to *I would not ever ...*, but again, I have no idea why.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Won’t* is certainly a contraction of *will not* (well, actually, the earlier *woll not*) and all three sentences are grammatical, including the second one. Ernest Hemingway wrote in ‘Across The River And Into The Trees’:

> I will get into the *motoscafo* . . .and . . . we will not ever see one
>   another again.

There is no difference in meaning between the three, but each might be used on different occasions.

Answer (score 18):

The only contraction in that sentence is *won't*, which (always) means *will not*. None of the other words would be affected when you expand the contraction.

Thus, *...will not ever be the same* is the proper way to understand this sentence.

That said, *...will never be the same* is grammatical, as well. In speech, people either use the contracted version or the *will never* combination. Rarely do you hear someone say (in US English) *will not ever*.

All three versions, however, are grammatically correct and are identical in meaning.

Comment: This is primarily because "will not ever" is awkward to say.

Comment: +1 to me, "will not ever" places an extra emphasis on "not" and thus could enjoy extra effect.

Comment: Will not ever seems redundant; why use three words when two will do?